# Drupal 7 form_alter removes form field completely

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook-form-alter

I am trying to alter a form field, specifically in Drupal commerce but when I use the hook form alter, it removes the field altogether and just adds my alteration. Even if I do not add a field alteration, just simply declaring the field will also remove the field.

How can I just alter a form field, without losing the rest of the field.

```
function custom_theme_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout'){

    $form['cart_contents'] = array(
      'prefix' => 'my alteration'
    );


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I need to do it as an assignment vs altering the entire array.

```
$form['cart_contents']['#prefix'] = 'my alteration';
```

Comment: Hey accept this as the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.